# Non-PIE Binary Livecode mergExt

Tags: ios

I´ve sent an update of an iOS App developed with LiveCode but this time the update was rejected by Apple saying the App "is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables."

Do you know how is this problem fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your application with a loader at following location:

https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/9692/ios-app-rejected-with-non-pie-binary-error.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep these three points

1 setup the Deployment Target is iOS4.3 or later

2 your project target [Build Settings]，modify Don't Create Positon Independent Executables to "NO"

3 your project target [Build Settings],modify Generate Position-Dependent Code to "NO"